# How can I manage Memgraph Docker instances using Python?

Tags: memgraphdb

I'm developing Python based graph-based applications I want manage different Memgraph database server instances directly from Python.

Can this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[GQLAlchemy](https://memgraph.com/gqlalchemy) `instance_runner` module allows you to start, stop, connect and monitor Memgraph instances with directly from your Python scripts.

First, perform all the necessary imports:

```
from gqlalchemy.instance_runner import (
    DockerImage,
    MemgraphInstanceDocker
)
```

The following code will create a Memgraph instance, start it and return a connection object:

```
memgraph_instance = MemgraphInstanceDocker(
    docker_image=DockerImage.MEMGRAPH, docker_image_tag="latest", host="0.0.0.0", port=7687
)
memgraph = memgraph_instance.start_and_connect(restart=False)
```

Start querying the database with:

```
memgraph.execute_and_fetch("RETURN 'Memgraph is running' AS result"))[0]["result"]
```

You can pass configuration flags using a dictionary:

```
config={"--log-level": "TRACE"}
memgraph_instance = MemgraphInstanceDocker(config=config)
```

To stop a Memgraph instance, call the `stop()` method:

```
memgraph_instance.stop()
```

To check if a Memgraph instance is running, call the `is_running()` method:

```
memgraph_instance.is_running()
```